# Как вернуться через getSupportActionBar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled с сохранением состояния?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как можно сохранить состояние предыдущего Activity (в частности скрола в RecyclerView)?, при возврате через нажатие кнопки Backward, определенную через:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

В то время, как при нажатии, на клавиатуре на системном Backward положение скрола в RecyclerView сохраняется

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() и onRestoreInstanceState()
Вот пример:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerview-scroll-position-with-recyclerview-state-or-no

Comment: Испробовал вариант по ссылке, однако состояние не сохраняется. Под дебагом видно, что при возврате в MainActivity, Bundle в onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) всегда равен null. Может быть Bundle где-либо обнуляется при возврате  через setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) !?!? Пытаюсь разобраться...

Comment: Если нужно просто прокрутить список до нужного элемента, самый дешевый способ будет запомнить первый видимый элемента при перехода, а при возврате поставить список на эту позицию.

Comment: Если мы говорим о lastFirstVisiblePosition, то так пробовал, однако возможна ситуация, что пользователь нажал на карточку, верхний край которой, к примеру в 1 пиксель заходит за экран. Тогда при возврате, эта карточка будет считаться неактивной и будет перемотка на следующую по порядку.

Comment: Получилось реализовать. Ответ см. ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно осуществить через вызов onBackPressed() и, важно, завершить обработку нажатия пункта меню (кнопки Home) через замену `return false` на `return true`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Возврат c сохранением статуса родительского Activity происходит также, если дочерний Activity вызван через startActivityForResult. В этом случае изменение 'return false' становится излишним.